# How to get current route via useRoute outside of router-view component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite

How can I get the current route using `useRoute` for a component that's *outside of* the `<router-view />`? Is this possible?

**Breadcrumbs.vue**

```
<script setup>
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.name) // undefined
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <Breadcrumbs />
  <router-view />
</template>
```

The alternative is that I have to put `<Breadcrumbs />` at the top of every single view component, and I was hoping to avoid that and instead just include it once in my `App.vue`

Comment: It seems like your route does not have a name. Can you show the of of `console.log(route)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`route.name` is `undefined` in your example because that's the initial value when the component is rendered *before the route has resolved*.

For the component to reactively update based on the current route, use a watcher (e.g., [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) or [`watchEffect`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect)):

```js
import { watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()

watchEffect(() => {
  console.log(route.name)
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-watch-route-name?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FBreadcrumb.vue)

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction! And thanks for the demo. Another option I've learned is to use something like: `const route = useRoute(); 
const name = computed(() => route.name);` then in my template: `<div>name is {{name}}</div>`

Answer (score 2):

In your main file, try to mount app like this

```
router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app');
});
```

then useRoute() should be ready in your component